# persistence JPA

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I have a Entity class

public Candidatos() {
    }

```
public Candidatos(Integer identificacion) {
    this.identificacion = identificacion;
}

public Integer getIdentificacion() {
    return identificacion;
}

public void setIdentificacion(Integer identificacion) {
    this.identificacion = identificacion;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getApellido() {
    return apellido;
}

public void setApellido(String apellido) {
    this.apellido = apellido;
}

public String getCurso() {
    return curso;
}

public void setCurso(String curso) {
    this.curso = curso;
}

public Integer getVotos() {
    return votos;
}

public void setVotos(Integer votos) {
    this.votos = votos;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (identificacion != null ? identificacion.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Candidatos)) {
        return false;
    }
    Candidatos other = (Candidatos) object;
    if ((this.identificacion == null && other.identificacion != null) || (this.identificacion != null && !this.identificacion.equals(other.identificacion))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "entidades.Candidatos[ identificacion=" + identificacion + " ]";
}
```

}

and my JPA controller

public class CandidatosJpaController implements Serializable {

```
public CandidatosJpaController(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    this.emf = emf;
}
private EntityManagerFactory emf = null;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}

public void create(Candidatos candidatos) throws PreexistingEntityException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(candidatos);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (findCandidatos(candidatos.getIdentificacion()) != null) {
            throw new PreexistingEntityException("Candidatos " + candidatos + " already exists.", ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

public void edit(Candidatos candidatos) throws NonexistentEntityException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        candidatos = em.merge(candidatos);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
            Integer id = candidatos.getIdentificacion();
            if (findCandidatos(id) == null) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The candidatos with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
            }
        }
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

public void destroy(Integer id) throws NonexistentEntityException {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Candidatos candidatos;
        try {
            candidatos = em.getReference(Candidatos.class, id);
            candidatos.getIdentificacion();
        } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
            throw new NonexistentEntityException("The candidatos with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
        }
        em.remove(candidatos);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

public List<Candidatos> findCandidatosEntities() {
    return findCandidatosEntities(true, -1, -1);
}

public List<Candidatos> findCandidatosEntities(int maxResults, int firstResult) {
    return findCandidatosEntities(false, maxResults, firstResult);
}

private List<Candidatos> findCandidatosEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        cq.select(cq.from(Candidatos.class));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        if (!all) {
            q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
            q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        }
        return q.getResultList();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

public Candidatos findCandidatos(Integer id) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        return em.find(Candidatos.class, id);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}

public int getCandidatosCount() {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
        CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
        Root<Candidatos> rt = cq.from(Candidatos.class);
        cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
        Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
        return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

}

But when i instance the class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Candidatos candi = new Candidatos();
    candi.setIdentificacion(1);
    candi.setNombre("juan");
    candi.setApellido("ovalle");
    candi.setCurso("1001");
    candi.setVotos(1);
    CandidatosJpaController control = new CandidatosJpaController();
```

say me constructor CandidatosJpaController in class  CandidatosJpaController cannot be applied to given types, requiered: EntityManagerFactory.

What happen?
because if i create a empty constructor 
say me:
           Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
           Not supported yet.
       at controladores.CandidatosJpaController.(CandidatosJpaController.java:31)
           at votaciones.Votaciones.main(Votaciones.java:26)

Comment: The error message is pretty clear I think. There is no no-arg constructor.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but JPA is quite complex. And if you don't master the basics of Java (like constructor arguments), you'll hit walls every time. Learn the Java basics with simple programs first.

Comment: **cannot be applied to given types, requiered: EntityManagerFactory** means you are passing something else rather than **EntityManagerFactory** to the CandidatosJpaController custructor

Answer (score 0):

Are you still need a solution? Or maybe other user need it.

Change your constructor with this:

```
CandidatosJpaController control = new CandidatosJpaController(Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("XXX"));
```

Replace `XXX` value with your persistence unit name, see your `persistence.xml` to know it.